# I GET ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, typeerror, addeventlistener

I have the following code snippet and I am not sure why the event listener is not working. It gives the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

```
var btn = document.getElementById("button");

var priceshow = document.querySelector("#price");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

    XHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (XHR.readyState == 4 && XHR.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(XHR.responseText);
            var price = data.bpi.GBP.rate;
            priceshow.innerText = price;
        }
    }

    var url = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json";
    XHR.open("GET", url);
    XHR.send();
}
```

Comment: Because you don't have element with id `button`.

Comment: works for me here - https://jsfiddle.net/nhe2sbmz/

Comment: add a breakpoint (there are tutorials on the web) and inspect `btn` to see if it is defined. Alt you can do a `console.log('button', btn)` right before you add the event listener. More than likely you don't have an element with Id of Button. Also why use querySelector when you are selecting by ID?

Answer (score 1):

`btn = document.getElementById("button");`
btn is null because it could not be found (an element with id button). I don't think the button has the id button.